Starting AnyLogic Simulation Model with alpyne in Python
# Hi everyone,  I'm having trouble starting/connecting my AnyLogic simulation model in Python using the alpyne library. Here are the details:
Environment:
Operating System: macOS
Python Version: 3.12
AnyLogic Version: AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.9.1
Java Version: "22.0.2" 2024-07-16
anylogic-alpyne Version: 1.2.0
Directory:
    `/Users/kaisuhr/PycharmProjects/ML_Anylogic_PPS/
├── ModelExported/
│   ├── model.jar
│   ├── model.zip
│   └── [contents of model.zip extracted separately]
├── RL_Anylogic.py
└── .venv/

Error Message:

`> When running my script, I get the following error message:
Failed to start AnyLogic simulation: ModelError\[path=, status=The underlying application failed to start. Check the logs., error=None, msg=''\]

2024-09-19 15:06:51,111 \[alpyne.sim @ 338\]\[   ERROR\] ALERT! All attempts to kill process with ID 7006 failed! May requires system restart or manual quit to close.
Process finished with exit code 1\`

Here ist the relevant Code Part:
``{import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/kaisuhr/PycharmProjects/ML_Anylogic_PPS/Alpyne/alpyne')
import os
import numpy as np
from gym import Env
from gym import spaces
from stable_baselines3 import DQN
from stable_baselines3.common.logger import configure
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import EvalCallback
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv

from alpyne.data import SimStatus
from alpyne.env import AlpyneEnv
from alpyne.outputs import UnitValue
from alpyne.sim import AnyLogicSim

# Verify the model path

model_path = "/Users/kaisuhr/PycharmProjects/ML_Anylogic_PPS/ModelExported/model.jar"
java_path = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-22.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"

if not os.path.exists(model_path):
raise FileNotFoundError(f"Model file not found at {model_path}")

if not os.path.exists(java_path):
raise FileNotFoundError(f"Java executable not found at {java_path}")

try:
Load the AnyLogic simulation model with the specified Java path
sim = AnyLogicSim(model_path, java_path=java_path)
except Exception as e:
print(f"Failed to start AnyLogic simulation: {e}")
sys.exit(1)}`
`


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Path Verification: The path to the model.jar file is correct and the file exists.
Java Installation: Java is installed and the path to the Java installation is correct.
Logs: The logs are unfortunately empty and do not provide further clues.
Question:
What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it? Are there specific requirements or configurations that I might have missed?
